# Fortran executable runs in command line but not through Python script

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, spyder

I am trying to run a Fortran executable through a Python script but am getting an error. I can run the executable fine through the command line, but when I run this Python script inside Spyder it can't find a certain file. Below is the line of code I'm using and the output error:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["./genex"])
```

error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libgfortran.3.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/Austin/tycho-1-14/run/./genex
Reason: image not found
```

EDIT:

I did not find a solution to this particular problem, but I found that running the Python script from the command line instead of inside Spyder fixed the issue.

Comment: Probably because your environment variables are different in the two cases.

Comment: It may have found the executable, but it didn't find the gfortran runtime DLL. Is that installed in an unusual location?

Comment: It appears to be installed inside Spyder as well as several other location. My confusion likely stems from how Python is actually executing commands through subprocess. I figured that it just runs whatever command I give inside a command line like Terminal or iTerm would, but I guess that isn't the case.